# Difference between AS_SET and AS_SMART_SET of MessageDifferencer?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am using protobuf for my program(C++). Currently, I have to check the difference between two proto messages, for which I am exploring the [MessageDifferencer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer) tool.

For setting the [RepeatedFieldComparison](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.message_differencer#MessageDifferencer.RepeatedFieldComparison.details) parameter, I am not able to fully grasp the contrast between the *AS_SET* and *AS_SMART_SET* options?

I went through the documentation, it is mentioned that AS_SMART_SET is `Similar to AS_SET, but match elements with fewest diffs.`, *however* not able to find any detailed information.

Any suggestion in the right direction will do.

A bit of code to get the context:

```
using google::protobuf::util::MessageDifferencer;

MessageDifferencer differencer;

std::string report;
differencer.ReportDifferencesToString(&report);
differencer.set_float_comparison(MessageDifferencer::FloatComparison::APPROXIMATE);
differencer.set_repeated_field_comparison(MessageDifferencer::RepeatedFieldComparison::AS_SET/AS_SMART_SET);
```

I am talking about configuring the `set_repeated_field_comparison()` of the Messagedifferencer.